# Display or hide a Slidetoggle in JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, slidetoggle

I have a problem and i need some ideas to solve it:

I have a JSF wep page. The index have only ui:decorate and display some pages.
Each link in the webpage call the index.xhtml and all parts reload.

One of these parts is a menu and it can be displayed or hidden thanks a JQuery code with the SlideToggle function (Thanks to BalusC for help).

I have in the menu 4 sections with slidetoggle(). All of them starts closed (display: none).

The problem is when i click in some link in one of these sections (now displayed) the web refresh and now .... they are hidden again....

i think you know what i want. How can i solve that problem?

Thanks for all our help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax links instead of regular links and re-render only the portions which do not contain those panels

E.g. replace

```
<h:commandLink value="link" action="#{bean.action}" />
```

by

```
<h:commandLink value="link" action="#{bean.action}">
    <f:ajax execute="some" render="some" />
</h:commandLink>
```

---

By the way, instead of hassling with raw jQuery, you can also use just a JSF component which uses jQuery under the covers. For example, [PrimeFaces `<p:panel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel.jsf):

```
<p:panel toggleable="true" visible="false">
    ...
</p:panel>
<p:panel toggleable="true" visible="false">
    ...
</p:panel>
...
```

That's all.

Comment: mmmmm Ajax links?? 
I have links like that:
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{controlWeb.setContenido('main.xhtml')}" value="Index"/>
The Atribute "Contenido" is used to change one of the ui:decorate in the index to show another webpage.
Can you give me an example of a Ajax link?

Comment: Put `<f:ajax>` inside. See also [Communication in JSF2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxPOSTForm).

Comment: I think im going to use a PrimeFaces Panel because with Ajax i can change the Atribue but i need to call index for it can be readed again and show another web. Thanks for help BalusC